# TextInput and keyboard in react native android

Tags: react-native

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/egHA1.png)

the TextInput
 When the keyboard has popped up,controls handdled together
 sorry, my English is very poor
 please help me!

Answer (score 0):

You can use [keyboardavoidingview](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html) from `facebook` or another package like [keyboard-aware-scroll-view](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work. If keyboard appears, the whole page will squeeze.The bottom of the page will move up but the top won‘t

Comment: Then you should check by changing style of element. It should work.

Comment: Glad to help you :)