# React-Native Actual screen size when keyboard shows up

Tags: react-native

How can I get the actual screen height when virtual keyboard shows up? I need to readjust the view height dynamically when keyboard is active and in-active.

```
<View style={styles.container}>
   <TextInput
       autoFocus={true}>
   />
   <View style={styles.content}></View>
<View>
```

When the keyboard is present and dismissed how can I calculate the active screen height,

> content:{ height:  **?**}

Comment: check my answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44881130/6592263

Comment: have you tried <KeyboardAvoidingView> component instead of setting content's height by hands? https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html?

Comment: I tried for KeyboardAvoidingView as well , its not upto expectation, its still hiding some part of the view. I dont have any styles, then also. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Use this **[KeyboardAwareScrollView](https://github.com/APSL/react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view)** instead of **KeyboardAvoidingView**

keyboard avoiding view doesn’t quite work with the last element, and setting padding/margin didn’t work. So you have to add a new element to bump everything up a few pixels.

Try with **KeyboardAwareScrollView** which makes the scrolling interaction pretty seamless and gives a lots of other benefits like `resetScrollToCoords` and manage height calculation by its end.

Answer (score 0):

**KeyboardAvoidingView**

It is a component to solve the common problem of views that need to move out of the way of the virtual keyboard. It can automatically adjust either its position or bottom padding based on the position of the keyboard.

SOURCE:
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/keyboardavoidingview.html#relativekeyboardheight

Comment: but after minimizing the height , when keyboard is dismissed, previous height is not regained

Comment: @subhajit I had the same issue when I had `behavior='height'`, but it works fine with `behavior='padding'`